# Reacting to events triggered by API in C#

Tags: c#, events

I am using an API that has the following EventHandler:

```
static EventHandler<GPRSArgs> EventStateChanged
```

How can I receive these events in my client application so that I can react to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subscribe to the event.

lambda:

```
EventStateChanged += (sender, gprsArgs) => { do your thing }
```

delegate:

```
void Listener(object sender, GPRSArgs args)
{
    do your thing
}

EventStateChanged += Listener;
```

Answer (score 1):

just hook into this event. You gave few code but assuming your class name is MyClass you can do

```
MyClass.EventStateChanged += MyEventHandler
```

with

```
void MyEventHandler(object sender, GRPSArgs e)
{
 // ...
}
```

or hooking up with a lambda:

```
MyClass.EventStateChanged += (sender, e) => { /* whatever you want */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to it, as you would any other event.

I assume `APIClass` is the class the API has with the `EventStateChanged` event.

Somewhere in your code you subscribe to the event as below:

```
APIClass.EventStateChanged += EventStateChangedHandler;
```

This assumes you have a method as follows:

```
private void EventStateChangedHandler(object sender, GPRSArgs e)
{
    // Code to react to the event.
}
```

---

You could do this in one line, with a lambda:

```
APIClass.EventStateChanged += (sender, e) => { /* Code to react to the event */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you left out a `public` and an `event` in the declaration:

```
public class GPRSThingy
{
    public static event EventHandler< GPRSArgs > EventStateChanged;
    ...
}
```

Then use it

```
void DoSomething(GPRSArgs e)
{
    // whatever
}

var gprstThingy = new GPRSThingy();
gprstThingy.EventStateChanged += (sender, e) => { DoSomething(e); };
```

Sort of.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to subscribe to the event:

```
theClassWithEvent.EventStateChanged += 
    delegate (object sender, GRPSArgs e)
    {
        //process the event
    };
```

The event will also need to be called to alert all subscribers, from within `theClassWithEvent`:

```
if (EventStateChanged != null)
{
    EventStateChanged(someObject, new GRPSArgs());
}
```

Note the use of `someObject` above, because the exposed event is `static` you can't pass `this` and the `sender`, therefore will need to send something apt. Though, since you say you're using this from an API, I think we can assume that you don't need to make this call and should only subscribe to the event.